# Best practice reading table in S/4 Hana

Tags: abap

I found a program where in  loop with hundred records they are selecting from 12 different tables the description of a field value (e.g. umskz, fdgrv etc).
I know that the best way is to take the descriptions when I am getting the values of these fields through a join.
But if for some reason I do not want to do like this, which is the next best practice in order to get the descriptions?
By selecting from the tables for each record? or
by loading them in ITABs, and for each record read the ITABs and get the descriptions?
Of course, when I finish of getting the descriptions in the 2nd way, I will Free the ITABs.

I am looking forward for your opinions.

Thanks
Elias

Comment: As always, it depends on the exact case, of the volume of data, of tables buffered or not, of code complexity versus performance, etc. As a rule-of-thumb, querying the database once for all + reading from memory for every record, is generally faster than querying once per record, simply because database access is slower (even with in-memory databases). This rule-of-thumb is not even limited to HANA. But you ask a very [subjective question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), I don't see how it can be answered according to stackoverflow guidelines.

Comment: Thank you Sandra, you helped me a lot with your answer. I do not think that my question is a subjective one. It is about Best Practice. This program is a LOOP and SELECT, Loop & Select ... This is not good. What I did is to select almost all fields in  2 Select Joins and read in ITABs where I couldn't and use the Parallel techni;θε with Binary search. This old report in an old ECC6 SAP system (7.02) for 1 million kunnrs does 13 hours and 50 minutes and with the changes I made is running in 40 minutes on-line or 50minutes in the background. A programmer must follow BEST PRACTICES. Again Thanks

Comment: On a Hana Database it is best practise to push as much of your code as possible down to the database, be it via OpenSQL or CDS views.  There are several posts on scn.sap.com that covers the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a bit fuzzy, so let me first summarize what I understand:

You want to select a large set of data with 1M records from one "central" table. The data has 11 columns that contain codes. You want to join the descriptions for these codes.

Your setup sounds like a star schema. The best option, especially with SAP S/4 HANA, will usually be to create a CDS view that describes the required joins and produces output of exactly the form you need. This allows the database to perform expensive execution path calculations well before you are selecting the data, and thus allows the database to choose the optimal way to give you the data.

The second most efficient way to do this with SAP HANA will be a single OpenSQL SELECT that joins all data with LEFT OUTER joins in a single step. You already found this on your own, but let me repeat it in pseudocode for clarity:

```
SELECT 
    <central table>-<field list>,
    <first code table>-description AS description_1,
    ...
    <eleventh code table>-description AS description_11
  INTO TABLE DATA(data)
  FROM <central table>
  LEFT OUTER JOIN <first code table>
    ON <central table>-<first code field> = <first code table>-key
  ...
  LEFT OUTER JOIN <eleventh code table>
    ON <central table>-<eleventh code field> = <eleventh code table>-key.
```

The third best choice, which is what you are initially asking for, will usually be a pre-selection of the main data, followed by subsequent selections of the code descriptions, plus a final "join" in ABAP. Range tables may simplify selecting the required codes. SORTED tables may ensure the join provides acceptable performance:

```
" select the main data
SELECT <central table>-<field list>
  FROM <central table>
  INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE data.

" collect the codes
LOOP AT data REFERENCE INTO DATA(record).

  INSERT VALUE #(
      sign = 'I'
      option = 'EQ'
      low = record-<first code field> )
    INTO TABLE first_codes_range.

  ...

  INSERT VALUE #(
      sign = 'I'
      option = 'EQ'
      low = record-<eleventh codde field> )
    INTO TABLE eleventh_codes.

ENDLOOP.

" select the descriptions
SELECT <key>, description
  FROM <first code table>
  INTO TABLE first_descriptions
  WHERE <key> IN first_codes.

...

SELECT <key>, description
  FROM <eleventh code table>
  INTO TABLE eleventh_descriptions
  WHERE <key> IN eleventh_codes.

" join main data and descriptions
LOOP AT data REFERENCE INTO record.
  record->description_1 =
    first_descriptions[ <key> = record-><first code field> ]-description.
  ...
  record->description_11 =
    eleventh_descriptions[ <key> = record-><eleventh code field> ]-description.
ENDLOOP.
```

As @Sandra Rossi points out, performance is a highly individual thing that stands and falls with tiny details and often defies best practices. As a consequence, these suggestions can only ever be that: suggestions. The programmers that wrote the 13 hours job you are improving probably followed their best practices back then...

Comment: If your system is new enough (7.40 ehp5+) a CDS view is preferred to a calculation or analytical view.

Comment: An OpenSql select is not worse or slower than a view. If you retreive to the AS the same fields from the same tables with the same filtering (WHERE condition) you will get the same speed from OpenSql, a view or even AMDP.

Comment: Thanks Florian. What I have to say is that even in 2013 you are not going to KNB1 then Loop and get from KNA1 then KNVV, then BKPF .... This is not Best Practice. Even in 2013 there was Join or Parallel processing technique. Anyway, I like to write programs with less and efficient code.   Again thanks for the detail explanation.

Comment: @ekekakos, parallel processing should be your last resort, after everything else is fully optimized, and it is still not enough

Comment: @András I am not convinced that statements always provide the same speed as views. A statement urges the database to come up with an execution plan very quickly. Views give it more time to analyze and think during the activation phase. That may not be true for CDS views, which are barely more than some meta description. But I would assume that there is a difference to more complex view data structures, such as the cube-like Analytical Views. But I admit that this is guessing, I never really measured this.

Comment: @Florian, ultimately, views are consumed from OpenSql, and the WHERE condition can change from query to query. This means the execution plan is not created at activation, but at runtime.

Comment: I agree with @András, a view has always been a way of storing the best SQL query, they do not have a better performance than the corresponding SQL query (e.g. a `SELECT ... FROM view ...` being a join to 2 tables, is identical in performance to the equivalent `SELECT ... FROM table1, table2 ...`) - at least generally speaking, maybe in some cases, for some databases and so on, it could be better, or worse, who knows.

Comment: @Florian In HANA already optimized plans are stored in a plan cache - so a CDS view shouldn't trigger plan evaluation every time (if the statement hashes to one already cached)